# Apache Spark thrift server error: Kerberos principal should have 3 parts

Tags: apache-spark, hive, kerberos, thrift, spark-thriftserver

I am trying to start the Spark thrift server with Kerberos authentication enabled. To do so, I have these configurations in `conf/hive-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
<!--
    <property>
       <name>hive.server2.transport.mode</name>
       <value>http</value>
    </property>
-->
        <property>
             <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
             <value>KERBEROS</value>
        </property>
        <property>
              <name>hive.metastore.kerberos.principal</name>
              <value>thrift/iman@EXAMPLE.COM</value>
        </property>
        <property>
              <name>hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.principal</name>
              <value>thrift/iman@EXAMPLE.COM</value>
        </property>
        <property>
             <name>hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.keytab</name>
             <value>/opt/nginx/iman.keytab</value>
             <description>Keytab file for Spark Thrift server principal</description>  
        </property>
</configuration>
```

When I run the `start-thriftserver.sh` script, I get the following error in the logs:

```
18/02/19 18:16:57 ERROR ThriftCLIService: Error starting HiveServer2: could not start ThriftBinaryCLIService
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Kerberos principal should have 3 parts: spark
        at org.apache.hive.service.auth.HiveAuthFactory.getAuthTransFactory(HiveAuthFactory.java:148)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftBinaryCLIService.run(ThriftBinaryCLIService.java:58)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/02/19 18:16:57 INFO HiveServer2: Shutting down HiveServer2
```

Saying that the Kerberos princial name should be 3 parts, which is weird because it's already set as `thrift/iman@EXAMPLE.COM` in the XML configurations.

Also, I tried commenting out the **hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.principal** property to see whether it has any effect and as a matter of fact it does give a different error "No principal specified" when I do that.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In thrift/iman@EXAMPLE.COM, make "iman" into a fully-qualified host name.

Answer (score 0):

You need add the below content in the `core-site.xml` file:

```
<property>
   <name>hadoop.security.authorization</name>
   <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
   <value>kerberos</value>
</property>
```